# How can I change element attribute with $("this").change?

Tags: jquery

**Edit:** Thank you all for your suggestions. I've made suggested changes on my question. I edited the code, no syntax errors anymore, I get no errors from browser anymore.

This is the problem I'm dealing with now: I get the alert message "null" in each perform.

*I've been trying to change the value of an element with a checkbox, make the value "1" or "0" for a number of reasons.
 To check if I was successful, I placed an alert() inside the code to get the changed attribute. Whether I check or uncheck the checkbox, I only get "undefined" message. I think I'm messing up with synchronization but I don't know how.*

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
$("#checkTabsence").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
        var tutorPresence = document.getElementById("tutorCheckEl");
            tutorPresence.setAttribute = ("href", "1");
        var alertme = tutorPresence.getAttribute("href");
        alert(alertme)
    }
    else
    {
        var tutorPresence = document.getElementById("tutorCheckEl");
            tutorPresence.setAttribute = ("href", "0");
        var alertme = tutorPresence.getAttribute("href");
        alert(alertme)
    }    


});
  });
```

```html
<html>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkTabsence">
<a id="tutorCheckEl" style="display:none;"></a>
</html>
```

Comment: where is '#checkTabsence' ?

Comment: please add the rest of the html code

Comment: A few comments: 1) Post an [mcve]. You refer to `$("#checkTabsence")` but your example has no such element, 2) When using jQuery, you can avoid `document.getElementById("tutorCheckEl")` and use `$('#tutorCheckEl')`, and 3) Usually you will use `.val()` instead of `.attr("value")`

Comment: Sorry for lacking code. I'm editing it.

Comment: If you're using `document.getElementById`, don't use `#` before id

Comment: I corrected that too, now I get another error.

Comment: Your syntax for `setAttribute()` is wrong. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42098653/361762)

Comment: @AlexMcMillan: the "horde" wants to maintain quality here, and broadly does a good job. I don't think stirring up resentment against that is productive - may I suggest you raise a Meta question if you have a complaint? I have asked a moderator to take a look at your remark.

Comment: @halfer I disagree, and your response is indicative of the horde's distaste for helping people who come here with a specific problem instead of a generic issue future readers could benefit from.  I've raised issues like this many times on Meta, and they are always met with hilarious immaturity.  I'd rather show the OP support by making a comment like I did than try and fix "the establishment".  But thanks.

Comment: I hear you @Alex, and I understand the frustration. Nevertheless, the Meta community believes the site is going in the right direction. If there is another section of the community - such as yourself - that wants to change things, take it to Meta and make your case. My view is that you'll need to outline how quality will not suffer if question standards are relaxed (I also think this is impossible - question standard are specifically about quality).

Comment: (In any case, if people want to ask questions that don't meet any guidelines, they can post to Reddit and get an answer there).

Comment: @Ahmet: please don't add solutions in place of questions. We don't do that here. We prefer a clear and well-asked question, and then an answer below it. I've rolled back to revision 8, thought this probably isn't far enough - questions asked in reverse chronological order (update at the start?) aren't very clear for new readers, so you may wish to reorder it. Please add your answer below - we welcome self-answers here.

Comment: @halfer thank you for warning. I am getting used to format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a few problems:

1. You're trying to call `.attr()` on a plain DOM element but [`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) is a jQuery function. Either call [`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) on the DOM element, or use jQuery instead of getElementById.
2. You're forgetting the jQuery ID selectors need to be prefixed with a `#`. Change `$("tutorCheckEl")` to `$("#tutorCheckEl")`.
3. If you are going to use `.attr()` in jQuery, the syntax to set an attribute is `tutorPresence.attr("value", "1")`
4. If you are going to use `setAttribute()`, the syntax to set an attribute is `tutorPresence.setAttribute("value", "1")`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `$("tutorCheckEl")` matches against a `<tutorCheckEl>` which I doubt you have on the page.

Did you perhaps mean to use `$("#tutorCheckEl")`, which would match `<a id="tutorCheckEl">` (or indeed any element with `id="tutorCheckEl"`) ?

Also, an anchor tag (`<a>`) has no `value` attribute.  `value` is for input-type elements.

Comment: I edited code accordingly. Now I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'setAttribute' of null" error.